# Can an algebraic expression be made here.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

Okay, The price of a mandarin is 20 coins and the price of a guava is 15 coins, Find the number of mandarins and guavas that can be bought for 50 coins.

Now , can an alegebraic expression be used to solve this problem?

Suggest you ideas

Comment: Okay to find the number if you simplify you get 4m+3g=10; That not what 's needed.It's asked to find for 50. Any suggestions

Comment: Yes and no.  $20m + 15g=50$ is a single equation with two variables so it has infinite solutions.  However it may or may not have non-negative integer solutions.  You can divide both sides by 5.  $4m + 3g =10$  which should make it obvious.

Comment: This doesn't have infinite solutions. I don't know what market you buy your fruit in, but in any market that I've shopped you have to buy a whole fruit. So this is a Diophantine equation. It requires integers for both the number of mandarins and the number of guavas. There is a unique solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the given information it is clear that $$ 20x+15y=50$$ i.e $$4x+3y=10$$ since the no of unknown is greater than the   no of equation    the x and y has infinite no of solution.

But here it is important to notice that the x and y must be positive integer because  both of them represents the count of the fruits.

So from above equation $$x=\frac{10-3y}{4}$$. Here y =2 because any other y won't give you a integer values for x.when y=2,x=1 which are the solution.

NOTE: If it is asked to find the no of x and y that can be bought within 50  coins ,then replace the equal sign with <.

REMARK: Here x denotes mandarins and y denotes guavas.